# Scroll to the top by tapping on the system bar in the iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

When both (tool bar and post list) are not in top position:

> [image: all middle]

tapping on the system bar directly over the post list:

> [image: tap]

scrolls up tool bar first (user icon has appeared):

> [image: toolup]

And you need an extra tap to scroll post list to the top:

> [image: alltop]

Tapping on the system bar should scrolls list below tap position, like it implemented for questions area.

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)